# Is it possible to create a table with fixed headers using pure CSS that supports horizontal and vertical scrolling?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a scrollable table (both horizontally and vertically) with fixed headers. The table will be dynamically generated and will contain between 8 and 20 columns. The number of rows could be up to 10,000.

I've seen some similar examples on SO (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css+fixed+table+headers) and elsewhere. However, I cannot seem to find a **pure CSS** example that allows for horizontal scrolling. The closest I have come so far is http://codepen.io/johnryan1982/pen/LExbvZ. I'd appreciate if anyone could offer some pointers, and or explain as to whether this is even possible.

```css
section {
  width: 800px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 10em auto;
}
#output {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
colgroup {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
thead {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fdfdfd;
}
th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
.floatingHeader {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0%;
}
tbody {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 450px;
}
tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <!-- IE < 10 does not like giving a tbody a height. The workaround here applies the scrolling to a wrapped <div>. -->
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  <div class="old_ie_wrapper">
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <table id="output">
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <thead>
      <tr class="persistArea">
        <th>id</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>priority</th>
        <th>reporter</th>
        <th>timestamp</th>
        <th>col_A</th>
        <th>col_B</th>
        <th>col_C</th>
        <th>col_D</th>
        <th>col_E</th>
        <th>col_F</th>
        <th>col_G</th>
        <th>col_H</th>
        <th>col_I</th>
        <th>col_J</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="persistArea floatingHeader">
        <th>id</th>
        <th>status</th>
        <th>priority</th>
        <th>reporter</th>
        <th>timestamp</th>
        <th>col_A</th>
        <th>col_B</th>
        <th>col_C</th>
        <th>col_D</th>
        <th>col_E</th>
        <th>col_F</th>
        <th>col_G</th>
        <th>col_H</th>
        <th>col_I</th>
        <th>col_J</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>1419592785</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1420629585</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1420629585</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1420283986</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1420629586</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1418296786</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>1420283986</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1420629587</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1418987987</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1420283987</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1419247188</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1420629588</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1420111188</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1420111188</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1420111189</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1420629589</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1420456789</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>1419938389</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1419938390</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1418210390</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1420629590</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1419765590</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>1419851991</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>1420629591</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1419592791</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>26</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>1419938391</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1419765592</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>1419765592</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1419247192</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1420629592</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>31</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>1419074393</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>32</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1419247193</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1419765593</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>34</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1419074393</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>1420629594</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1419592794</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1419074394</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1419592794</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>1418555995</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>1418901595</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>1419938395</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>George</td>
        <td>1420197595</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1419679196</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>44</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1419938396</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>45</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1419938396</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>1420283996</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Paul</td>
        <td>1420629597</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1418728797</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>49</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Ringo</td>
        <td>1418987997</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>Unassigned</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Pete</td>
        <td>1418815197</td>
        <td>col_A_val</td>
        <td>col_B_val</td>
        <td>col_C_val</td>
        <td>col_D_val</td>
        <td>col_E_val</td>
        <td>col_F_val</td>
        <td>col_G_val</td>
        <td>col_H_val</td>
        <td>col_I_val</td>
        <td>col_J_val</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--[if lte IE 9]>
  </div>
  <!--<![endif]-->
</section>
```

Alternatively, I am not against rendering as a list. Would this be easier to implement?

Cheers!

Comment: Check out my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gbgmLV, is this kind of what you want? the header to stay in place while the table data scrolls?

Comment: @JustinBreiland - thanks for the response. It's similar to what I need in terms of the header remaining fixed for vertical scrolling, however the problem still exists for the horizontal scroll: the column headers [col_G, ... col_J] should not be visible, and those that precede [id, status, ... col_F] should align correctly with their corresponding data columns. When scrolling to the right, [col_G, ... col_J] should scroll into view in similar fashion to how the <tbody> data columns... Any ideas?

Comment: You need to remove it from within overflow:scroll... how are you generating the table?

Comment: So you do or don't want the table to scroll on the x-axis?

Comment: @DerrickWells - thanks for the suggestion. I'm looking into that at the moment. I'm using Dart to render the page; the data is being pulled from a remote location.

Comment: @JustinBreiland - I **do** want to have the table scroll on the x-axis

Comment: Are Your headers fixed values or will they change?  If they are fixed just use a <div> wrapper that holds a <div> for you headers and then make a table with the overflow:scroll

Comment: @DerrickWells - header values are fixed. Still not sure I follow, but have created a new CodePen (http://codepen.io/johnryan1982/pen/dPNvdr). Am I on the right lines...?

Answer (score 0):

I found this.. try this.  http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/

```
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

    tr:after {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
    }

    thead th {
        height: 30px;

        /*text-align: left;*/
    }

    tbody {
        height: 120px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    thead {
        /* fallback */
    }


    tbody td, thead th {
        width: 19.2%;
        float: left;
    }
```

This should help sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

please check my answer. it will help you a lot

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>data table demo</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            padding: 0px;
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .fixed-table-wrap{
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: scroll;
            height: 200px;
            -ms-overflow-style: -ms-autohiding-scrollbar;
        }
        .fixed-table-wrap table{
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .fixed-table-wrap table th, .fixed-table-wrap table td{
            padding: 10px;
            border:1px solid #c3c3c3;
        }
        .fixed-table-wrap table th {
            position: sticky;
            position: -webkit-sticky;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: 99;
            border-right: 1px solid #798ba9 !important;
            background-color: #c3c3c3;
        }
        .fixed-table-wrap table th::after{
            content: "";
            display: inline-block;
            width: 1px;
            background-color: #aba8a8;
            position: absolute;
            right: -1px;
            height: 40px;
            top: 0px;
        } 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fixed-table-wrap">
        <table id="example" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Position</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Office</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Start date</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                    <td>System Architect</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2011/04/25</td>
                    <td>$320,800</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>63</td>
                    <td>2011/07/25</td>
                    <td>$170,750</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                    <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>66</td>
                    <td>2009/01/12</td>
                    <td>$86,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                    <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                    <td>Edinburgh</td>
                    <td>22</td>
                    <td>2012/03/29</td>
                    <td>$433,060</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Airi Satou</td>
                    <td>Accountant</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                    <td>Tokyo</td>
                    <td>33</td>
                    <td>2008/11/28</td>
                    <td>$162,700</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                    <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                    <td>New York</td>
                    <td>61</td>
                    <td>2012/12/02</td>
                    <td>$372,000</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                    <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                    <td>San Francisco</td>
                    <td>59</td>
                    <td>2012/08/06</td>
                    <td>$137,500</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            
        </table>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should remove your link if you provide a snippet and instead describe how/why your solution works.